# store keyboard input into integer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, input

Just the start of my homework. Just need to figure this out so I can get the rest of the program going.

I need to be able to type input such as:

```
3 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

with spaces separating each number, and each number being in the array in the order typed.

```
array[0] = 3, array[1] = 5
```

This MUST be in C and typed in console per crazy professor. Not allowed to press the return key after each number is entered. Must be entered as shown above and then the return key.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the input to go into the array with it being input like this. This is only the start of my homework assignment, i've been trying for a while and can't figure this out.

Comment: Try google: "read command line arguments in C"

Comment: @Scape: Are these command line arguments or input to stdin?

Comment: input to stdin, sorry i was going to add that and forgot.

Comment: Is the size of the integer array known before you actually start entering the values?

Comment: The most will be 18. But most of the time will be around 8-12 integers. Will eventually be implementing 3 & 4 variable k-maps. Just the input must be like this. The first number will be the variable count and the second is the number of minterms..then the minterms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't do your work for you, but look up [reading in strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/gets/) from standard input, and then how to [tokenize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) (split) them into elements that can be stored in an array.

Comment: It's usually common courtesy to leave a reason for a downvote. I don't see any technical problem with my answer, and the downvote isn't much of a clue, either. I don't mind a downvote, so long as you explain why. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I haven't been able to get on the computer to try it (middle of moving) I will check this out and hopefully be able to figure it out!